# discord rpc application login unsuccessful error

Tags: node.js, discord-rpc

I had a issue with my app shutting down when discord wasn't launched on desktop because of RPC.

```
rpc.login({
    clientId: "clientid"
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Now when I added the catch block it doesn't shut down when it cannot connect but it shows a pretty long error to the user, which I would like to hide or replace with a smaller console log like "RPC offline" or something

```
Error: Could not connect
at Socket.onerror (C:\snapshot\test\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\transports\ipc.js:32:16)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:514:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

ofcourse i tried to use normal try-catch and only `.catch(error)` instead of `.catch(console.error)` but that doesn't seem to catch the unsuccessful connection and just shuts down the script again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rpc.login` method returns a **[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** which if fails to fulfil ( [rejected promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#description) ) throws an error, your approach was absolutely correct to use `Promise.prototype.catch` & `try/catch` and from what I can understand by your question

> I would like to hide or replace with a smaller console log like "RPC offline".

You can simply pass a `console.log` statement when you catch the error in your promise like so:

```js
rpc.login({
    clientId: "clientid"
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(`RPC Offline`)
});
```

Or use `try/catch/finally` - ( Suggested if retrying to login multiple times )

```
try {
    login(rpc);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(`RPC Offline`)
}
finally {
    console.log(`Could not connect therefore retrying to login`)
    login(rpc);
}


async function login(rpc) {
    await rpc.login({
        clientId: "clientid"
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I added the catch block it doesn't shut down when it cannot connect but it shows a pretty long error to the user, which I would like to hide or replace with a smaller console log like "RPC offline" or something

You mean you want to do something like `.catch(() => console.log("RPC Offline"))`?

> ofcourse i tried to use normal `try-catch` and only .catch(error) instead of `.catch(console.error)` but that doesn't seem to catch the unsuccessful connection and just shuts down the script again.

Because it's a promise and you can't handle rejections via `try-catch` unless you are `await`ing